# Weird polynomial factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

I encountered a polynomial $z^6+1=0$ where z takes complex value. And I tried to factorize it. So I first solved the equation and got $z= i , -i $,since the polynomial is of order 6, then I can conclude both roots are of order 3. So finally I got $z^6+1=(z-i)^3(z+i)^3=(z^2+1)^3$ which is really weird. Can somebody explain this to me please?
PS:  My friend told me it might be related to finite field.

Comment: What is it that you think is WEIRD??

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Isn't it obvious? I mean, the equality $z^6+1=(z^2+1)^3$ is clearly false...

Comment: It's best to write the number -1 in general polar form $e^{i  \pi + 2 \pi n}$ where n denotes full circles, then apply the sixth root to it

Comment: @DietrichBurde I explain OPs equation by saying he made a mistake. Because he did. In saying "then I can conclude both roots are of order 3".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Lol, a typo. I agree, no need to discuss. I believe that occam's razor supports my hypothesis, but obviously, you disagree. I can't change my previous typo, however, si I am deleting the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error was in saying:

> then I can conclude both roots are of order 3

Which is false. In fact, both roots are of order 1. There are other roots, and they are all of the form $$e^{(1+k)\cdot \frac{2\pi}{6}}$$ for some value of $k$.

This has nothing to do with finite fields and everything to do with complex numbers, especially the identity $$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x.$$

Answer (score 3):

Your factorization is incorrect:
$$z^6+1=(z^3-i)(z^3+i)\neq(z-i)^3(z+i)^3.$$
In fact, the roots are $\omega^k$, $k\in\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$, where $\omega=e^{\pi i/6}=\sqrt{3}/2+i/2$.

Finite fields are irrelevant. You should look up 'roots of unity' and 'cyclotomic polynomials'.

Answer (score 1):

Over a field of characteriostic $3$ we have
$$
z^6+1=(z^2+1)^3,
$$
and this is the probably a reasonable way to explain this equation.

Comment: I disagree. I mean with the "this is the only way". I believe the OP actually made a mistake, because he said "then I can conclude both roots are of order 3". It is perfectly reasonable to explain his result by working in complex numbers and saying he made a mistake.

Comment: Well, perhaps. But since he mentions finite fields, I suspect he took it from another context.

Answer (score 0):

The roots are not of order 3.

If a root of $f(x)$ is
of order $n$,
then
$0 = f(x) = f'(x)
=...
=f^{(n-1)}(x)
$.

What you *can* conclude
is that,
since $i$ and $-i$
are roots,
then
$x^6+1$
is divisible by
$(x-i)(x+i)
= x^2+1
$.

This is also
an immediate consequence of
$z^3+1
=(z+1)(z^2-z+1)
$
so that,
setting
$z = x^2$,
$x^6+1
=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)
$.

This should enable you
to get the other roots.